# how to get the value of a variable outside of the if statement

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

Is it possible to use the value of my variable *value1* which is in an if else statement and  plug it in an equation which **has to be outside** of the if else statement.

Every time that I run the program I get a value of 0 for my variable *value1*

```
int value; 
int value1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity3); 

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
    button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    final Random r=new Random(); 
    value = r.nextInt(4 - 1 + 1) + 1; 

    if (value == 1) {
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                value1 = r.nextInt(4 - 1 + 1) + 1;      
            }
        });
    } else (value == 2) { 
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                value1 = r.nextInt(4 - 1 + 1) + 1;      
            }
        });
        // equation 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you set your `OnClickListener`s based on the value of a random number? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: How many times have you run this? What was the value of `value` for each time. If value > 2 then `value1` will be `0`. If you are not supplying a random seed to `r` then it may be generating the same number each time.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in using `Random` class.
`Random` creates sequence of pseudo random numbers. Every time you create new instance of `Random` and call `nextInt()` you get the same number. To change this behavior you should use seed: any integer that you pass as an argument to `Random()` constructor.

Typically people use current time as a seed :

```
Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int n = r.nextInt();
```

This code will create different number on each program invocation.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant for his question?

Comment: This is relevant to the problem. Indeed OP thinks that his problem is in getting value from if statement, but actually he does not understand why variable `value1` always gets the same value.

Comment: Ahh I see. Didn't think of it like that =)

Comment: @AlexR : According to the docs for the `Random()` constructor... **"Constructs a random generator with an initial state that is unlikely to be duplicated by a subsequent instantiation. The initial state (that is, the seed) is partially based on the current time of day in milliseconds."** Or am I misreading things?

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question: Yes, you can.
Take the following example:

```
int value = 10;
int value1;

if (value == 10) {
    value1 = 6;
}

System.out.println("Value1: " + value1);
```

This will work and will give the output of 6. And as you can see I've used the value outside of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be achieved, but you have some other issues with that code, have you tried to compile it?

- I don't think `value` can ever be 1, and you haven't handled all the possible cases
- else (value==2) needs to be else if (value==2), although you might consider a switch statement
- using the same seed for random results in the same output each time

As for your actual question can you get value1 outside of the if? You have already declared the variable outside of the if - you've declared it at member level so you are already able to access it anywhere in the class